# Стороны света

Tags: этимология

Мне интересно происхождение названий сторон света. С западом и востоком все понятно. А что за слова "север" и "юг"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**СЕВЕР** - «одна из четырех сторон света, противоположная югу». Слово имеет праславянские корни. Соврем. его форма развилась из др.-рус. сѢверъ «север» вследствие изменения в рус. яз. Ѣ в Е и утраты слаб. кратк. гласн. ъ (ср. от сѢверъ укр. сівер «холод»; рус. диал. сиверко «холодно», где из Ѣ < ei  развился и (i)). Др.-рус. сѢверъ происходит от праслав. *sěu-er-os, что значит «левый»: древние, совершая моления, жертвоприношения и т. п., смотрели на восток, северная сторона оказывалась у них левой. В слове* sěu-er-os корень *sěu- «левый» и суф. -er-os. Ср. от* sěu- «левый» с суф. -j-os образовано *seu-j-os, давшее* suji, «левая» (чередов. s/'/s). От него происходит др.-рус. шуии «левый» (ср. фамилию Шуйский — как бы «принадлежащий левше»).

**ЮГ** - «одна из четырех сторон света, противоположная северу», «местность, расположенная в полосе теплого климата». По корню праслав. В данном звуков. виде заимствовано из ст.-сл. яз., в котором слово *югъ* «полуденная сторона, полуденный ветер» содержит нач. звук [j]. В рус. и укр. говорах отмечается форма *юга* «сухой туман в жаркий летний день». 
Эта форма, как видим, тоже имеет звук j, no отличается от ст.-сл. слова тем, что относится к жен.р. и выражает иное знач. В др.-рус. памятниках встречаются слова *югъ* и *угъ* «юг», а также *ужьныи* «южный, обращенный к югу» (см. ужин). Полагают, что 
в слав. языках формы с j вторичн., развившие этот звук в нач. слова для прикрытия гласного. Первонач. же была форма *uga > yгa «полдень» (ж.р.), собств. «сторона, откуда солнце сильнее всего светит и идет тепло».

Comment: Цитата про "север" из этимологического словаря Цыганенко. В других словарях даётся другая версия.

Answer (score 0):

Древнее русское слово СЕВЕР, в котором присутствует, также древний корень, русский корень ВЕР. Корень ВЕР, во всех словах где он присутствует, означает ВЕРтеть, ВЕРтеться, ВЕРтящийся. Слово СЕВЕР, созвучно со словом СВЕРЛО, и должно писаться оно как СЕ-ВЕР, то есть СЕ ВЕРТИТСЯ или СИЕ ВЕРТИТСЯ (ось Земли), или СИЯ ВЕРТИТСЯ (имея ввиду Землю и указывая на её ось), или СЕЙ ВЕРТИТСЯ (имея ввиду полюс Земли).
Справка: В исходной системе древнерусского языка различались три указательных местоимения: тъ, та, то; онъ, она, оно и сь, си, се, которое могло выступать и в виде сей, сия, сие. Каждое из этих местоимений имело свое значение и употреблялось лишь в определенных случаях: тъ, та, то — для безотносительного указания; онъ, она, оно — для указания на отдаленные предметы; сь, си, се — для указания на ближайшие предметы. Таким образом СЕВЕР это область около вертящегося полюса Земли.
Кстати, использование местоимения СЕ — как указание на ближайшие предметы, указывает на то, что предки наши жили недалеко от полюса Земли. Может именно поэтому истинная этимология стирается из нашей родовой памяти…