# Этимология слова "север"

Tags: этимология

Кто может пояснить происхождение слова *север*?

Comment: А ещё очень интересно, точно нет связи "севера" с английским 'severe', суровый, или всё-таки есть. В словаре пишут, что severe из латыни, связано с serious, но вдруг и с нашим севером связь есть. Это было бы очень логично. ;)

Comment: Я хотел сказать не логично, а естественно для таких сопутствующих понятий.

Comment: Повтор Вопроса на сайте, который неведом нашему чувашскому партнёру.

Comment: Левша на старославянском - Шульга. И к северу никакого отношения не имеет.
Старославянское название - пивночь. Так же как и юг - полудень

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой В словаре Шапошникова говорится, что это удивительное случайное совпадение.

Comment: @grizzly а ссылки у Вас нету?

Comment: @Alex При чём тут левша?!

Comment: @Артём Луговой Сможете скачать по [этой ссылке](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/search.php?req=%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2+%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9&open=0&res=25&view=simple&phrase=1&column=def)? (В колонке Mirrors нужно кликнуть на какой-то цифре, если не получится, тогда на другой).

Comment: @grizzly Спасибо, я тут нашёл: ftp://istorichka.ru/Slavjanovedenie/Shaposhnikov_Etimol._slovar%60_sovremen._russkogo_jazyka/T.2.2010.pdf. Да, интересно оказалось, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

> Слово "Север" имеет древнерусские корни. Раньше встречалось в форме
>   сѣвер (через "ять") и "сивер". Означает "холод", "холодный ветер".
>   Лингвисты усматривают, что в основе слова "север" лежит
>   индоевропейская основа "keuero". Современные лингвисты быстро образуют
>   цепочку: "север" - "сивер" - "сибер" - "Сибирь".

[Источник](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/129992-otkuda-v-russkom-jazyke-slova-jug-i-sever.html).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из словаря Фасмера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ещё [источник](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5442/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0), неподалёку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Галина, почему у вас в ответе вместо ятя — ер?

Comment: Видимо, не везде конвертировался. Ять отображается только в скриншотах. Попробую сейчас скопировать и восстановить справедливость. Есть! **ѣ**!

Answer (score 0):

Из праиндоевропейского ***cee̯u̯er*** "северный ветер"

Comment: Разве первая буква "c", а не "k"? См. для примера этимологический словарь Шапошникова.